# First come, first save in ParallelTable parallelization

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

**Short version of the question:** In [C++'s OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852852/1317944), I know how to get what I want, but I'm wondering whether Mathematica has the same option. It's called "dynamic scheduling" when parallelizing.

**Long version of the question**: Say I'm evaluating a parametrized expression, `MyFunc[i]`, where the evaluation time depends on `i` and is not constant. I would like to use my full computer power with `ParallelTable`:

```
result = ParallelTable[MyFunc[i], {i,1000} (*, Method -> [what should this be?] *)];
```

I would like to have ParallelTable evaluate `MyFunc[i]` on "first come first server" basis. In other words: Keep all Kernels busy as long as any instance of `MyFunc[i]` is not evaluated until the number of parallel kernels available (threads) is higher than the number of remaining evaluations of `MyFunc[i]`.

I noticed that Mathematica decides how the parallelization is done *before* the evaluation. This also seems to be the case in the documentation. All the options provided for `Method->` decide on how to split the list, not how to evaluate the list.

So: Is there a way to get the parallelization as "first come first serve"?

Comment: If you have an idea about how runtime of `MyFunc` depends on its argument, then this (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108035/21606) is related and goes into the same direction as the answer by @andre.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a expert, but it seems that `ParallelSubmit` does what you need.

Here is a little program that has behavior you describe :

```
ParallelTable[
     Print[i, " ", $KernelID]; 
 If[i == 1, Pause[4], Pause[1]];
 $KernelID,
{i, 1, 6}]
```

> [image]

As the evaluation of the first item (i=1) needs 4 seconds and the evaluation of the other ones needs 1 second, the kernel that execute the first item should be used only once. This is not the case.

If you use the following code  :

```
h1 = Table[
       ParallelSubmit[{i},
         Print[i, " ", $KernelID]; 
         If[i == 1, Pause[4], Pause[1]];
         $KernelID],
    {i, 1, 6}]
WaitAll[h1]
```

Then you have :

> [image]

The kernel that executes the item 1 is used once.

This is also visible in real time on the panels of `h1`.

**EDIT**

It turns out that if the option `Method -> "FinestGrained"` is added to `ParallelTable` , it works fine too. Finally, I'm not sure the `ParallelSubmit`is usefull for the OP's problem :

```
ParallelTable[Print[i, " ", $KernelID];
 If[i == 1, Pause[4], Pause[1]];
 $KernelID, {i, 1, 6}, Method -> "FinestGrained"]
```

[image]

Comment: I will try it and let you know if it works as expected. Thanks.