# Elegant way to partition list to be faster than `ParallelTable` (using `ParallelSubmit`), or some alternative?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, parallelization, partitions

Suppose you have a function

```
fun[x_] := (Pause[.05*x]; x^2);
```

of which you know that its evaluation time increases with its argument - in this case obviously linearly. Consider the following piece of code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
CloseKernels[];
list = Range[1, 12];
listparallel1 = Partition[list, 3];
listparallel2 = {{1, 5, 12}, {2, 6, 11}, {3, 7, 10}, {4, 8, 9}};
f11 := (Table[fun[i], {i, listparallel1[[1]]}]);
f21 := (Table[fun[i], {i, listparallel1[[2]]}]);
f31 := (Table[fun[i], {i, listparallel1[[3]]}]);
f41 := (Table[fun[i], {i, listparallel1[[4]]}]);
f12 := (Table[fun[i], {i, listparallel2[[1]]}]);
f22 := (Table[fun[i], {i, listparallel2[[2]]}]);
f32 := (Table[fun[i], {i, listparallel2[[3]]}]);
f42 := (Table[fun[i], {i, listparallel2[[4]]}]);
```

Now compare timings:

```
LaunchKernels[4];
DistributeDefinitions[f11, f21, f31, f41, f12, f22, f32, f42];
res1 = Table[fun[i], {i, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 3.905648 *)
res2 = ParallelTable[fun[i], {i, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 1.670125 *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 res3tmp = {ParallelSubmit[f11], ParallelSubmit[f21], 
   ParallelSubmit[f31], ParallelSubmit[f41]};
 res3 = Flatten@WaitAll[res3tmp];]
(* 1.674126 *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 res4tmp = {ParallelSubmit[f12], ParallelSubmit[f22], 
   ParallelSubmit[f32], ParallelSubmit[f42]};
 res4 = Flatten@WaitAll[res4tmp];]
(* 1.068721 *)
```

We see, `ParallelTable` already does a goodish job, but since it does not have the insight into the function as we do, this can be optimized via `ParallelSubmit`. Since runtime increases with elements in `list`, it is natural to partition the list as done in `listparallel2` and clearly, timings for `res4` are much better than for the `ParallelTable` version `res2`.

My question is, what is an elegant way to partition `list` into the form of `listparallel2` such that I provide a number of sublists `n` (here, `n=4`) and it then fills the first sublist starting with first and last element of `list`, going on to the second sublist with second and second to last element of `list` and so on.

Alternatively, how can one determine the optimal distribution of jobs to parallel kernels?

### Update

Unfortunately, the first method in the answer by @unlikely leads to kernel crash on my machine for sufficiently large problems (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108314/21606)). Since I am using Mathematica 10.0.1 I cannot use the second method in unlikely's answer because `RepeatedTiming` and `EchoFunction` are not available. So, even if it is not the most optimal way - I am again interested in a customized `Partition` like function, that brings `list` into the form of `listparallel2`.

Comment: `RepeatedTiming` and `EchoFunction` are just for benchmarking. You can remove all these calls and the following `//Last`. You can also use the sub/optimal partitioning as of my second answer.

Comment: @unlikely Thanks for all your effort!  I actually believe that I did that, but it returned an empty list. Will try again later when I have access to my computer again and report back .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a common jobs-to-resources assignment problem.

Suppose you have $n$ jobs (long running) to be distributed across $m$ resources working in parrallel and each job $i$ takes a time $c_i$ to be completed. Define the following decision variables:

- $x_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$ and it's $1$ if the job $i$ is assigned to resource $j$
- $y_j \ge 0$ is the total time required for the resource $j$ complete his work (the definition/use of these variables is not mandatory)
- $z \ge 0$ is the whole time required to complete all jobs

Obviously you have some constraints:

- $\sum_{j=1}^m x_{i,j} = 1$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ because each job must be assigned to exactly one resource
- $y_j = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_{i,j}$ for all $j=1,\ldots,m$
- $z \ge y_j$ for all $j=1,\ldots,m$ because $z = \max_j y_j$

Now your objective function is $z$ (to be minimized).

This can be done with `LinearProgramming`:

```
n = 12;
m = 4;
costs = Range@n/2 // N;

vars = Flatten@{
    Array[x, {n, m}],
    Array[y, m],
    z
    };

constraints = Flatten@{
    Table[Sum[x[i, j], {j, m}] == 1, {i, n}],
    Table[y[j] == Sum[x[i, j] costs[[i]], {i, n}], {j, m}],
    Table[z >= y[j], {j, m}]
    };

bm = CoefficientArrays[Equal @@@ constraints, vars];
solution = LinearProgramming[
   Last@CoefficientArrays[z, vars],
   bm[[2]],
   Transpose@{-bm[[1]], 
     constraints[[All, 0]] /. {Equal -> 0, GreaterEqual -> 1}},
   vars /. {_x -> {0, 1}, (_y | z) -> {0, \[Infinity]}},
   vars /. {_x -> Integers, (_y | z) -> Reals}
   ];


Cases[Pick[vars, solution, 1], x[ij__] :> {ij}];
GroupBy[%, Last -> First] // Values // SortBy[First]
```

The answer is

> {{1, 3, 6, 10}, {2, 4, 12}, {5, 7, 8}, {9, 11}}

that tell you the optimal distribution of the jobs across the resources.

Indeed with this approach the time required to complete the work is:

```
Pick[solution, vars, z]
```

> {10.}

while with your approach is

```
listparallel2 = {{1, 5, 12}, {2, 6, 11}, {3, 7, 10}, {4, 8, 9}};
Plus @@@ (listparallel2/2) // Max
```

> 21/2

Obviously the whole optimization process takes times, and for short jobs is not necessary.

---

You can also use the simple Minimize to get the another optimal result

```
n = 12; m = 4; c = Range@n/2 // N;
solution = Minimize[{z, {
          Table[Sum[x[i, j], {j, m}] == 1, {i, n}],
          Table[Sum[c[[i]] x[i, j], {i, n}] <= z, {j, m}],

          Table[{x[i, j] \[Element] Integers, 0 <= x[i, j] <= 1}, {i, 
            n}, {j, m}]
          }},
        Flatten@{Array[x, {n, m}], z}
        ] // RepeatedTiming // EchoFunction["Timing:", First] // 
     Last // EchoFunction["Optimal value:", First] // Last;
GroupBy[Cases[solution, (x[ij__] -> 1) :> {ij}], 
  Last -> First] // Values
```

> Optimal value: 10.
>
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 12}, {9, 11}}

Comment: Many thanks! This seems to be a really nice approach. Would you mind elaborating a little bit on what your constraints represent? I would like to fully understand this approach using `LinearProgramming`

Comment: @Lukas I added an introduction. You can also check my answrs to the follwoing questions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47211/elegant-solution-to-the-zebra-logic-puzzle-einsteins-riddle?s=1|1.0737 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107859/puzzle-with-mathematica because I used `LinearProgramming`

Comment: Thanks alot! This goes beyond what I imagined and excellently answers my question. Now that you have explained the constraints it is all clear. Also thanks for further references, will take a look.

Comment: @Lukas Thank you, although I do not know if it responds to your initial question as this optimization deserves to be made for long jobs

Comment: I agree, it does not 100% answer the question as it is formulated because I ask for some way to `Partition`. Yet, my actual problem is some sort of a `Table` with many elements where timings scale linearly with big slope. Your approach is way better than the approximation I asked for in these cases. I extended the question a little

Comment: Unfortunately, there is an issue. The kernel crashes if `n` is larger than a certain threshold. I'll put this issue into a new question and update this question accordingly. Sorry for revoking the Accept (temporarily), but until this is solved I would like to leave the question "open".

Comment: I decided to accept this answer again. The kernel crash seems to be unique to some configurations.

Comment: @Lukas, are you sure the Kernel crash is caused by LinearProgramming and not, for example, while evaluating some of its arguments? Try building arguments before maybe

Comment: I will investigate this issue. I'll soon be at work and hope that I can reproduce it there (different system), and if so, I will try what you suggested - otherwise I need to wait until I'm back home

Comment: I am pretty sure it must have to do with `LinearProgramming`. Everything that is set before the `LinearProgramming` and everything that is called inside evaluates instantly without any issues (even for very large `n`). Only when I evaluate the `LinearProgramming` the kernel crashes after while. On a Linux x64 running 10.0.2, the kernel seems to stay kind of alive but Mathematica does not return a result even after an hour - and it seems to freeze.

Answer (score 1):

Following your today comment, I'll add another answer with another method of partitioning.

If you can accept a sub optimal partitioning, you can also apply the following strategy:

```
n = 12; m = 4;
j = Range@n;
c = j/2;

jd = Fold[
   MapAt[Append[#2], #, Ordering[Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}], 1]] &,
   Table[{{0, 0}}, m],
   Transpose@{j, c} // SortBy[Minus@*Last]
   ][[All, 2 ;; -1]];

jd[[All, All, 1]]
Max@Total[jd[[All, All, 2]], {2}]
```

> {{12, 5, 4}, {11, 6, 3}, {10, 7, 2}, {9, 8, 1}}
>
> 21/2

Comment: Thanks! Although this is not optimal, it at least yields solutions reliably without crashing kernel...