# Customized `ParallelTable` - Automate `ParallelSubmit` - Possibly an issue with `HoldAllComplete` attribute

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, hold

Related to [this question and in particular its answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108035/21606) I am trying to wrap everything into a new `parallelTab` function that takes into account some cost per job, computes the optimal distribution of jobs to the cores and uses `ParallelSubmit` to, well, submit them.

Let's just focus on the case that the optimal distribution is already known, e.g. here

```
ClearAll[fun, vals, distribute, f, submit];
CloseKernels[];
fun[x_] := (Pause[.05*x]; x^2);
vals = Range[1, 12];
distribute = {{1, 3, 6, 10}, {2, 4, 12}, {5, 7, 8}, {9, 11}};
LaunchKernels[4];
```

`fun` is the function with imbalanced timing and `distribute` tells us how to submit jobs `1` to `12` to 4 parallel kernels so that the computation time is minimized. If the number of kernels is known I can proceed like this

```
f[i_] := Table[fun[x], {x, vals[[distribute[[i]]]]}];
DistributeDefinitions[f];
AbsoluteTiming[submit = {ParallelSubmit[f[1]], ParallelSubmit[f[2]], ParallelSubmit[f[3]], ParallelSubmit[f[4]]}; Print[submit]; Flatten[WaitAll[submit]][[Ordering@Flatten@distribute]]]
```

which works fine and yields a factor of `1.7` speedup compared to the naive `ParallelTable` approach and almost a factor of `4` compared to the `Table`. However, the goal is to let `parallelTab` have an argument, say `numKernels`, that specifies the number of cores to be used. For this purpose, I would like to automate the `ParallelSubmit` part in the above code, so that a list with necessary `ParallelSubmit`s of proper `f[i]` is generated (this particular code is not working and is the part I am asking for help - let's assume `numKernels` has been fixed to `4`). What I tried is this:

```
submit2 = Table[ParallelSubmit[f[i]], {i, 4}]
rules = Table[{Rule[i, j]}, {j, 1, 4}];
submit3 = ParallelSubmit[f[i]] /. rules
```

Neither of them works. To my understanding, `submit2` fails because `ParallelSubmit` has `Attributes` `HoldAllComplete`, resulting in a list `{ParallelSubmit[f[i]],ParallelSubmit[f[i]],...}`. Actually on the first glance, `submit3` seems to do what I want, see here

[image]

However, a `WaitAll` yields failure (although at least one kernel seems to do what it is supposed to):

[image]

How can I automate the procedure of `ParallelSubmit`ting the tasks. I believe that must be possible but my knowledge about advanced usage of `Hold` and its relatives is just too little to solve that trick on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works :

```
submit4 = Table[With[{i = i}, ParallelSubmit[f[i]]], {i, 4}]
WaitAll[submit4]
```

> {{1, 9, 36, 100}, {4, 16, 144}, {25, 49, 64}, {81, 121}}

You can find a explanation about `With` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/5467) (chapter entitled "With", paragraph "Advanced Use")

Comment: Thank you very much! Also very nice reference for explanation. Using `With`for such injections inside `Hold` is very useful, good to know that for future :)