# Kernel crashes during `LinearProgramming`. Can you reproduce it?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, crash

Using the code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108048/21606) for a sufficiently large problem setting crashes my kernel. I'll copy/paste the code here:

```
n = 12;
m = 4;
costs = Range@n/2 // N;

vars = Flatten@{
    Array[x, {n, m}],
    Array[y, m],
    z
    };

constraints = Flatten@{
    Table[Sum[x[i, j], {j, m}] == 1, {i, n}],
    Table[y[j] == Sum[x[i, j] costs[[i]], {i, n}], {j, m}],
    Table[z >= y[j], {j, m}]
    };

bm = CoefficientArrays[Equal @@@ constraints, vars];
solution = LinearProgramming[
   Last@CoefficientArrays[z, vars],
   bm[[2]],
   Transpose@{-bm[[1]], 
     constraints[[All, 0]] /. {Equal -> 0, GreaterEqual -> 1}},
   vars /. {_x -> {0, 1}, (_y | z) -> {0, \[Infinity]}},
   vars /. {_x -> Integers, (_y | z) -> Reals}
   ];


Cases[Pick[vars, solution, 1], x[ij__] :> {ij}];
GroupBy[%, Last -> First] // Values // SortBy[First]
```

Running this for `n=40` yields a result almost instantly, whereas `n=60` leads to this

[image]

after a minute or so. I am using Mathematica 10.0.1 on Windows 8 64bit. Can you reproduce this behavior? If so, do you have an idea why it is happening?

**Small update**
The kernel crash really appears to be due to `LinearProgramming`. Everything that is set before or is called within `LinearProgramming` evaluates basically instantly without issues. Only when `solution` is evaluated, the kernel crashes - on a Linux x64 it stays alive but Mathematica 10.0.2 freezes and does not return a result even after an hour.

Comment: Confirmed on Mathematica 10.3.0.0, OS X 10.10.5, after 10 minutes running. No idea, though. I thought `Dynamic` was only related to front-end operations.

Comment: Absolutely no problem in Mathematica 10.3.0 Windows 8.1 x64. Response is immediate, even faster than with n=12.

Comment: Works ok on 10.0 for Mac OS X.11.3 x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)

Comment: Does it actually crash (i.e. the kernel process exits due to some error like segmentation fault), or does it just lock up?  Can you clarify this point in the question and edit the tags accordingly?

Comment: Works fine on 10.3.1 Win 7 Pro 64bit

Comment: @Szabolcs Interestingly enough, it won't crash anymore on my Windows machine. It just refuses to return something - even after two hours. Very weird...